# Merging different windows in tmux

Tags: unix, tmux

my question is simple. I have two windows in tmux session, 1 and 2. How can I merge these two windows into one window split horizontally/vertically? I couldn't find an answer in manpage, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you're looking for `join-pane`:

```
join-pane [-bdhv] [-l size | -p percentage] [-s src-pane] [-t dst-pane]
              (alias: joinp)
        Like split-window, but instead of splitting dst-pane and creating a new pane,
        split it and move src-pane into the space.  This can be used to reverse
        break-pane.  The -b option causes src-pane to be joined to left of or above
        dst-pane.
```

You can use this with the command-line (`C-b :`).

Comment: This sounds like a great answer, but I'm still struggling with the syntax. Would you mind adding a short example? how are src-pane and dst-pane expected to be specified?

Comment: Details on how to specify panes here, but basically you can use numbers. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#:~:text=target-pane%20(or%20src-pane%20or%20dst-pane)